# Trying to rewrite getMediaDir in Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options

Tags: magento-1.7, module, overrides

I have successfully managed to change the destination of CMS wysiwyg folder thanks to Marius, [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/my-new-module-does-not-fire-or-im-missing-something-obvious-please-help) but that is relative to media dir that is defauled to ./media.

Now I have made module to change the core fn getMediaDir but somehow I think it is somewhere else defined,, but I can't find where?

This is what I defined for module:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7vY.png

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mk_Hub>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mk_Hub>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <hub>
        <class>Mk_Hub_Helper</class>
      </hub>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <hub>
        <class>Mk_Hub_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>hub_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </hub>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <config_options>Mk_Hub_Model_Core_Config_Options</config_options>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

and :

```
<?php
class Mk_Hub_Model_Core_Config_Options extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options
{

    public function getMediaDir()
    {
        return $this->getBaseDir().DS.'media' . '/' . 'subdir1');
        // return $this->_data['media_dir'];
    }



}
```

Comment: ...why would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this myself (the need has never occured)

Have a look at app/etc/config.xml, and you will find:

```
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
```

I am sure you can just change the default media path here by placing the directives in your app/etc/local.xml

Comment: HI @proxiblue, I tried that but that didn't worked.. I think that is used during setup for magento.. (the default values) right?

Comment: Pity, was hoping this would be a quick fix. Maybe someone can shed some light what these are exactly for, and how they can be used....

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go down the rabbit hole all the way, but I did find an easy way and it's in the options in admin backend ( System -> Configuration -> General -> Web ) unsecure and secure.  You can alter the Base media URL or any other if you need to.

Or you can do it programmatically like this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig( 'web/unsecure/base_media_url', '{{unsecure_base_url}}media/subdir1/' );
```

Comment: If you don't want to persist it (calling saveConfig will store to db) you can set it just for *this session* by calling setConfig instead)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite the Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options class using XML rewrite because at the time the class Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options is initialised, Magento hasn't loaded the XML files. Look at the __construct function in the Mage_Core_Model_Config:

```
public function __construct($sourceData=null)
{
    $this->setCacheId('config_global');
    $this->_options         = new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options($sourceData);
    $this->_prototype       = new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base();
    $this->_cacheChecksum   = null;
    parent::__construct($sourceData);
}
```

Magento does not use the Mage::getModel(...), it calls new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options directly.

The only way to overwrite this class is to create the same file structure under local, so it will be local/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php. But it is not recommended. :)